# Node not added to tree

Tags: java, tree

I've been trying to create a `integer binary search tree` with Java and for some reason, I've been going wrong with adding new nodes to the tree.

Here is the `NODE` class.

```
class NODE
{
    NODE left = null, right = null;
    int info;
    public NODE(int x)
    {
        info = x;
    }
}
```

and here's the `BST`(Binary Seatch Tree) class with the `insert()` method.

```
class BST
{
    NODE tree = null;
    public void insert(int x)
    {
        NODE node = new NODE(x);
        NODE temp = tree;
        while(true)
        {
            if(temp == null)
            {
                temp = node;
                break;
            }
            else if(temp.info > x) temp = temp.left;
            else temp = temp.right;
        }
    }
    //other methods present here
}
```

For reasons that I could not figure out, the  `insert()` method is going wrong.

The object `tree` carries `null` in it even after the `insert()` method is called.

Can you find something spotty in the code?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to name classes beginning with a capital letter, but not entirely in caps--save the all-caps values for final variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a recursive `insert` method in the `NODE` class (instead of utilizing an infinite loop as you did):

```
public void insert(int x) {
        if(x < this.info) {
            if(this.left == null)
                this.left = new NODE(x);
            else
                this.left.insert(x);
        }
        else {
            if(this.right == null)
                this.right = new NODE(x);
            else
                this.right.insert(x);
        }
    }
```

And your `BST` class would have the following `insert` method (simply calls the other `insert` method):

```
public void insert(int x) {
    if(tree == null)
        tree = new NODE(x);
    else
        tree.insert(x);
}
```

The main `insert` method is in the `NODE` class because it must recursively call itself on nodes within the tree.

Comment: Updated my answer... this works (tested in Eclipse). Any questions about it?

Comment: Thanks @asaini007 . This worked for me as well.
Any idea on where I went wrong?

Comment: The idea that after the line `NODE temp = tree`, doing something like `temp = node` would change `tree` is false. The line `NODE temp = tree` creates a `NODE` object whose value points to the value of `tree`. If, for example, you used a helper method to change the _value_ of `temp`, it would also change the value of `tree`. However, the line you used, `temp = node`, doesn't alter the value of `temp` - it reassigns it altogether, pointing it to the value of `node`. So perhaps your code could work if that line instead changed the _value_ of `temp` (using a helper method in the `NODE` class).

Answer (score 1):

Of course tree remains null - you don't assign anything to this field. 
After temp = tree; and temp = node; only temp is changed, not tree.

Answer (score 0):

The insert() method should insert the child of a node into the tree, calling an already declared Node as a parameter.  e.g.:

```
//Returns true/false depending on whether the insert is successful
public boolean insert(int x, Node node, boolean leftChild) {      
    if (node == null) return false;
    Node child = new Node(x);
    if (leftChild) {
        if (node.left != null) return false;
        node.left = child;
    } else {
        if (node.right != null) return false;
        node.right = child;
    }
    return true;
}
```